# getelementbyClassName in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to write this code in angularjs:
I am passing $event to a function and getting its parent then need to get all tags with a class name.

```
    elem = $(e.target).parent();
    var checkpoint = elem.parent().parent();
    var checklist = checkpoint.parent();
   //var checkpoints = checklist.getElementsByClassName('point');
    var checkpoints = angular.element(checkpoint).$document.getElementsByClassName('point');
```

Here lastline is not wokring in angular JS.

Answer (score 1):

use `find()` selector: to find the the children element with .point class

```
 var checklist = checkpoint.parent();
 var checkpoints = checklist.find('.point');
```

or use *[querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)*;

```
checklist.querySelectorAll(".point")
```

Comment: I tried this but querySelectorAll not working with checklist.

Comment: then checkpoints  not having any children with *point* class . check the dom or print checkpoints  in console ...